# Magento Module Ajax Request Returning 404 Error

Tags: php, ajax, magento, magento2

I'm facing an issue with my Magento Module. It is working well on localhost, however when uploaded to the server, any Ajax request made returns a 404 error. I have created a Magento 2 Module in the Namespace Emps_MAMIntegration. I have also created a `routes.xml` file in `etc/frontend/routes.xml` with the following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="mamform" id="mamform">
            <module name="EMPS_MAMIntegration" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

In my template file, I'm making an ajax request to a file  `Controller/Index/Number.php` as follows:

```
 $.ajax({
          url: '<?= $block->getUrl('mamform/index/number') ?>',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
               type: 'model',
               make: make
           },
           success: function(data) {
              // handle success
            },
           error: function(error) {
                    // error handling
           }
 });
```

Then in my `Number.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Emps\MAMIntegration\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use EMPS\MAMIntegration\Helper\MamService;


class Number extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    private $mamService;
    private $resultJsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        MamService $_mamService,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory

    ) {

        $this->mamService = $_mamService;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {


        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        // var_dump($post);
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER'));
            return;
        }

        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $type = $post['type'];

       /// omitted for brevity
      return $resultJson->setData(['models' => $data]);

    }
}
```

On localhost, all ajax request work as expected, and returns all data. However when I upload the module to the production environment, they fail with Error 404.

Comment: You wrote `Numbers.php`, is the file named `Numbers.php` or is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento's routing might be case sensitive depending on server configuration

Your module name is **EMPS_MAMIntegration** but your namespace is **Emps\MAMIntegration**.
I would bet on this being the reason for it working on some environment and not the other.

Try renaming your module to **Emps_MAMIntegration** or show us your register.php file. Also make sure module is enabled on production.

Comment: Renaming the module solved the issue. Thank you very much.